# Output rsults to div #results

Tags: javascript, html

So I built a palindrome program and I am scratching my head as to why the results won't print to the selected div.

here is the JS

```
    function palindrome(str) {
    var re = /[W_]/g; 
    var lowStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(re,'');
    var splitStr = lowStr.split('').reverse.join('');  
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    if(splitStr === lowStr) {
      results.innerHTML ='This IS a palindrome';
    } else {
      results.innerHTML ='This is NOT a palindrome';
     }
   }
 palindrome();
```

Comment: The pen is here: http://codepen.io/UluaWebDev/pen/PzGKGo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `palindrome()` is called without any parameters when it is expecting the string as parameter. In this case `undefined` will be passed.

So, this should result in error

> cannot read `toLowerCase()` of `undefined`.

---

The regex you're using is incorrect.

`/[W_]/g` will match all the `W` and `_` any number or times.

You need `\W` which will match any non-alphanumeric characters.

```
var regex = /[\W_]/g;
```

---

One more thing is that the function `reverse` should be invoked by adding `()`.

```
var splitStr = lowStr.split('').reverse().join('');
                                       ^^            // Call
```

**There are many logical errors in the code.** Here's [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba4mgkg5/).

```js
function palindrome(event) { // sets function
 event.preventDefault();
    
    var str = document.getElementById('input').value;
    // regEx removes all non-alpha numeric characters

    var re = /[\W_]/g;
    // converts string to lower case and applies regex
    var lowStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(re, '');
    // convert string characters into array, reverses and joins output back in into string
    var splitStr = lowStr.split('').reverse().join('');
    // conditional statement to check if input is a palindrome

    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    if (splitStr === lowStr) {
        results.innerHTML = 'This IS a palindrome';
    } else {
        results.innerHTML = 'This is NOT a palindrome';
    }

    return false;
}
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin:400,700";
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #222;
    background: #222;
    font: 62.5% / 1.6 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #69b4f1;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#69b4f1, #1277c8);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#69b4f1, #1277c8);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    padding: 5em 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.title-block {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.title-block h1 {
    font-size: 6vmin;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
}

.title-block h3 {
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 3vmin;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: justify;
}

.title-block h3 span {
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 105%;
    @inlcude ts;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
    box-align: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -moz-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-align-items: stretch;
    -o-align-items: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
}

form input,
form button {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.4);
    font-size: 3vmin;
}

form input {
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 4;
    -moz-flex-grow: 4;
    -webkit-box-flex: 4;
    flex-grow: 4;
    -ms-flex-positive: 4;
}

form button {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -moz-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    background: #f1a669;
    background: #f1a669;
}

form button:focus,
form button:active,
form button:hover {
    background: #ed8a3a;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
    transition: color 0.3s;
}

#results {
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="title-block">
        <h1>Palindrome Checker</h1>
        <h3>A <span>palindrome</span> is a word, phrase, or sentence that reads the same backward and forward.</h3>
    </header>
    <form>
        <label for="input"></label>
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a word, phrase, or sentence..." />
        <button onclick="palindrome(event)">Check Palindrome</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My main concern is getting the function to print to my div id= "results".

Comment: @LuisRodriguez If the ID of the element is correct and there exists only one element with that ID, it should work. If not working, please create live demo with complete code.

Comment: for some reason it works in Jfiddle, but not codepen